# How do I find an available nickname in Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

The app keeps asking for a nickname, and I have entered dozens of names, but it keeps saying that the names aren't available. How can I find an available name?

Comment: Find one that is available and use that?

Comment: Can you give some samples of what you've tried? I found that taking my normal nickname and adding some random numbers at the end did the trick.

Comment: I'm having trouble with it as well. It's probably related to the high server load problem they're having at the moment.

Comment: This is crazy, I think it's a bug, because no way the username which I chosen can exist. I think they're just forcing you to use numbers, and I don't want to use numbers in my nickname.

Comment: @mlibby, ugh... random letters in a name. It is a NAME! numbers are cheating! (though to be fair, it is by far the easiest method)

Comment: @Ash, for some reason, I have 2 accounts with the same exact name and it did not get mad at me and make me choose another name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to look at available names for Pokémon Go.

Your only real option is to keep trying usernames. There are still a few considerations that might make it easier to find a username you are happy with:

- **The more simple the name, the more likely it will already be taken**: Simple usernames are usually the first to go. This includes simple words, or names.
- **Consider using deliberate misspelling**: You might consider simply trying the same username with some degree of misspelling. For example, I often get away with replacing "the" for "teh", when faced with a username I really want that has already been taken.
- **Consider adding a number**: A common way to 'reuse' a name is to simply add a number to the end of it. Assuming you add a 4 digit number to the end of your username, you essentially go from having a single possibility to ten thousand possibilities. This number might be randomly selected, or have personal meaning to you, such as a birthday or a favored console system.
- **Consider "l33t sp34k"**: You might also consider replacing alphabetical characters with numbers. "Leet speak", where you replace alphabetical characters for numbers that have similar appearance, works best in these situations. Here are some possible considerations, if you choose to use "leet speak":

  - 1 : l|L
  - 3 : e|E
  - 4 : a|A
  - 5 : s|S
  - 6 : b|B
  - 7 : t|T
  - 0 : o|O