# How talk with a person by the nickname?

Tags: pokemon-go

Exist some directory for search persons by nickname in Pokemon Go? Some list with the contacts of them? Some way to find a person?

I want to find a person with the same nickname that me and talk with him or her. Maybe change the nicknames.

Comment: Maybe it's their name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find an available nickname in Pokémon Go?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274243/how-do-i-find-an-available-nickname-in-pok%c3%a9mon-go)

Comment: You can't.  There is no way for you to know who has which nickname.  That's private information.

Comment: Answer information does not belong in your question.  Now that it's been clarified, I think we can reopen this.  Now that that has happened, you can post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolution:** Don't exist any list of users and how contact they. I just need accept and let it go. Lot of people have fake accounts, is normal.

**Any way to get data from players?** Nop, the API of Pokemon just send data about items and pokemons, not about users.

**A person can change the nickname?** In the FAQ page of Niantic exist a information about it: you need open a support ticket and you can get a message in few weeks, but just will change the nickname in some cases.

**Any thing can I do?** nop. Just forget it.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, sorry.

Usernames are distributed on a first-come first-serve basis, and there is no directory (or any way to get the that information for that matter) as that information is sensitive and dangerous in the wrong hands (imagine if stalkers got access to nicknames).

As you said in a comment on the original post that the name is fake and very unlikely to be a real name, there is going to be no way to recover that username.

Niantic [does offer a way](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221964248-How-do-I-change-my-nickname-or-team-) to change usernames, but only in the case that the current name has personally identifiable information in it (real name, phone number, etc). There is also no mention of this username being released back into the available queue.

---

Additionally, Niantic has made as of yet no efforts to add any sort of communication method to this game, probably for good reason. If you want to talk to someone, you have to do it in real life, provided you really know who they are. The game (for the safety of all players -- especially children) offers no such way to talk through it.